# Why divide by 4! in the this combination?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Q)In how many ways can a pack of 52 cards be formed into 4 groups of 13 cards each?
According to me the answer must be $$ C^{52}_{13} *C^{39}_{13} *C^{26}_{13} *C^{13}_{13} * 4! $$ as the order is not important and there i saw other case of rearranging the 4 groups among themselves.
However, the in the answer, 
$$ \frac{C^{52}_{13} *C^{39}_{13} *C^{26}_{13} *C^{13}_{13}}{ 4!} $$
is given as the answer. Why do we have to divide it rather than multiply it?

Comment: How many ways can a deck of 4 cards be arranged into 4 groups of 1 card each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you want to group the numbers $1,2,3,4$ into two groups with 2 numbers each. Then the two following configurations are equal:

- One group contains $1,2$ and another group contains $3,4$
- One group contains $3,4$ and another group contains $1,2$

And thus you count them as one, or equivalently, you divide by the number of ways in which you can sort the resulting groups.

Comment: I think I got it. Since the order is not important, 4! won't be multiplied . But as you told above, the above case must be handled, the answer must be divided by n!. However, if the order does matter the answer would be multiplied by n! so as they can be rearranged by themselves too thereby cancelling n! in numerator and denominator and yield the C terms only.

Answer (score 0):

Because the order of the groups is not important you must count *fewer* of the arrangements.